# PyQt crashes and thread safety

Tags: python, multithreading, qt, pyqt4

Hello StackExchange community,

first off, you have all been a great help for me, thanks so much. First time question:

I am currently writing a PyQt GUI application and I see that it crashes on windows systems, also it gives me a segfault on my machine at home while it works on the one at work (both linux mint 17). After some research, I realize that I have probably created a thread-unsafe GUI because I have several objects that call each others methods.

> [From another stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8203812/4749250): *GUI widgets may be accessed only from main thread, meaning the thread that calls QApplication.exec(). Access to GUI widgets from any other thread – what you're doing with your calls to self.parent() – is undefined behaviour, in your case this means crashes.*
>
> [From Qt docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/threads-qobject.html): *Although QObject is reentrant, the GUI classes, notably QWidget and all its subclasses, are not reentrant. They can only be used from the main thread. As noted earlier, QCoreApplication::exec() must also be called from that thread.*

So in the end, I figure that I should only use the signal-slot system for doing so.

1. Is this correct?
2. Is this only needed for function calls, or can I manipulate the fields of some objects from other objects at runtime in a thread safe manner? for example, I have a options object that is accessed from multiple other objects, and I frequently change parameters there from different sources. Thread safe or unsafe?

The next thing, is that I have a problem recreating this thread-unsafe behaviour in example code. Qt documentation says that QObjects live in different threads. This means, the following Qt application should be thread unsafe (if I got it correctly).

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import sys

class TestWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self,string):
        super(TestWidget,self).__init__()
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton(string,parent=self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)
        
        # just to check, and yes, lives in it's own thread
        print self.thread()
        
    def buttonClicked(self):
        # the seemingly problematic line
        self.parent().parent().statusBar().showMessage(self.button.text())
        pass
    pass

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow,self).__init__()
        
        Layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        for string in ['foo','bar']:
            Layout.addWidget(TestWidget(string))
        
        CentralWidget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        CentralWidget.setLayout(Layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(CentralWidget)
        self.statusBar()
        self.show()
        pass
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    M = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

but it runs on my mine as well on windows machines fine.

3. Why? Is this actually thread-unsafe and could crash, but it just doesn't?

Thanks for helping me to sort this out ...

Answer (score 3):

**Is this correct?**

Yes, you should only use the signal-slot system for interactions ammong q-objects. 
This is how it's meant to be.

**Is this only needed for function calls, or can I manipulate the fields of some objects 
from other objects at runtime in a thread safe manner?**

> *I have a options object that is accessed from multiple other objects...*

If by objects here you meant Q-objects:

Your `options` object should have support for the signal-slot mechanism, you can achieve this
deriving `options` from  `QObject`.

```
class Options(QtCore.QObject):
    optionUpdated = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object)

    def __init__(self):

        self.__options = {
            'option_1': None
        }

    def get_option(self, option):
        return self.__options.get(option)

    def set_option(self, option, value):
        self.__options[option] = value
        self.optionUpdated.emit(self)
```

and then all widgets/objects using this options should have a slot that connect to this singal.

A simple example:

```
    options = Options()
    some_widget = SomeWidget()
    options.optionUpdated.connect(some_widget.options_updated)    // Is like you implement the observer pattern, right?
```

**Why? Is this actually thread-unsafe and could crash, but it just doesn't?**

`thread-unsafe` doesn't mean "the crash is guaranteed" but "this might crash" or "there is a high probability for this to crash".

From pyqt API doc [QObject.thread](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qobject.html#thread) :

> Returns the thread in which the object lives.

**Erratum**

As pointed by ekumoro, I've re-checked my previous position about each object leaving in a different thread, and ... I was wrong!

`QObject.thread` will return a different **QThread instance** for each object but `QThread` is not actually a thread is just a wrapper for those threads provided by the OS.

So the code don't really have the problem af several object sliving in different threads.

<del>I have modified the code you have used for demostration a little bit for simplicity:</del>

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import sys

class TestWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self,string):
        super(TestWidget,self).__init__()
        # just to check, and yes, lives in it's own thread
        print("TestWidget thread: {}".format(self.thread()))

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow,self).__init__()
        print("Window thread: {}".format(self.thread()))
        Layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        for string in ['foo','bar']:
            Layout.addWidget(TestWidget(string))
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    M = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

<del>and yes, this prints:</del>

```
Window thread: <PyQt4.QtCore.QThread object at 0x00000000025C1048>
TestWidget thread: <PyQt4.QtCore.QThread object at 0x00000000025C4168>
TestWidget thread: <PyQt4.QtCore.QThread object at 0x00000000025C41F8>
```

<del>demostrating each control lives in its own thread.</del>

<del>Now, you have the signal-slot mechanism to deal with this "thread-safely", any other approach will not be thread-safe.</del>

Comment: thanks for your answer. But I don't understand the example code, and this must be because I am missing something in the signal-slot system or threading. In your code, an external object retrieves a value from `options` by calling it's `get_options` function. By this, if my external object lives in another thread, it performs an across-thread function call that was said to be problematic. Now in your code, the signal is emitted after the value is set, merely notifying `some_widget` that something has happened to `options`. Or not?

Comment: @grgrsr It was only an ilustrative example, when you emit the signal you can emit just the option value that has chaged, not the entire option object, that way you not perform a cross-thread function call.

And yes after the option is set, a signal is emitted notifying ALL objects connected to it that some option has changed.

Comment: @RaydelMiranda. Your answer is mostly okay, but your claim that "every control lives in its own thread" is completely false. All your example code is showing is that a new `QThread` instance is created every time `self.thread()` is called. Remember that `QThread` is not actually a thread! It is simply a wrapper that manages a thread that is ultimately provided by the OS.

Comment: @ekhumoro, You are right, I did a little more dig into API dock and debug the code while running and there is no such thing as a thread for each QObject, thanksm answer edited.

Answer (score 2):

Answers to your questions:

1. GUI widgets can only be accessed from the main thread (the one that runs
   `QApplication.exec_()`). Signals and slots are thread safe by default since
   Qt 4
2. Any call leading to **direct** Qt graphics objects manipulation from another thread than the main one is **not** thread-safe => will crash
3. There is no threads involved in the code of your question (where are the threads???),
   **it's not true that different QObjects live in different threads**. Maybe the crash you have has nothing to do
   with threads ?

Comment: thanks to your answer as well. If `self.thread()` returns the thread of the object, then yes they do live in different threads: Running the example on my computer produces
`<PyQt4.QtCore.QThread object at 0x7f22a6099c30>
<PyQt4.QtCore.QThread object at 0x7f22a6099d60>`

[Qt docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/threads-qobject.html) _A QObject instance is said to live in the thread in which it is created. Events to that object are dispatched by that thread's event loop. The thread in which a QObject lives is available using `QObject::thread()`._

Or what am I missing here?

Comment: @mguijarr take a look to my answer (at the end), QObjects does indeed lives in different threads.

Comment: I agree it seems those QObjects are living in different threads - however, I am more than surprised!!! Imagine you have 100 widgets in your application, then Qt creates 101 threads??? It's crazy. So I am missing something here... Do you have more information?

Comment: @mguijarr. You are correct to doubt this: see my comment to Raydel's answer.

Comment: @mguijarr, sorry man, I was wrong!!! ekhumoro is right. I misunderstood the API doc, after doing a couple of experiments I see the truth.

Answer (score 1):

As a follow-up to some of the comments, below is an test script that shows how to check which thread the code is executing in:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Worker(QtCore.QObject):
    threadInfo = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object, object)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def emitInfo(self):
        self.threadInfo.emit(self.objectName(), QtCore.QThread.currentThreadId())

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Test', self)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.thread = QtCore.QThread(self)
        self.worker1 = Worker()
        self.worker1.setObjectName('Worker1')
        self.worker1.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self.worker1.threadInfo.connect(self.handleShowThreads)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.worker1.emitInfo)
        self.worker2 = Worker()
        self.worker2.setObjectName('Worker2')
        self.worker2.threadInfo.connect(self.handleShowThreads)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.worker2.emitInfo)
        self.thread.start()

    def handleShowThreads(self, name, identifier):
        print('Main: %s' % QtCore.QThread.currentThreadId())
        print('%s: %s\n' % (name, identifier))

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.thread.quit()
        self.thread.wait()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: thank you, that was very helpful. Unfortunately, I can't vote up your answer because I don't have enough reputation ... but as a follow up question: I have put `QtCore.QThread.currentThreadId()` in the constructors of each of my objects, always returning the same ID! so ... to complete my confusion, all my objects do in the end live in the same thread?

Comment: @grgrsr. All your objects will live in the same thread that they were created in, unless you explicitly move them to another one using `moveToThread`. In your example code, there is only one thread (i.e. the main GUI thread), and so `currentThreadId` will always return the same thing. In your question you say the Qt docs state that "QObjects live in different threads". This is not true, so I think you must have misread something.

Comment: @grgrsr.  As for your segfaulting program: it's impossible to diagnose without seeing actual code, but it's most likely caused by object ownership issues. Do the crashes only happen when the program exits? If so, this is a quite common problem, and is caused by python deleting objects in an unpredictable order when the interpreter shuts down. There are various ways to fix it, but it very much depends on the specifics of how the application is written.

Comment: thanks for the clarification of the threading issue. For the (then unrelated) problem of the crashes: They don't happen on exit, program runs fine on at least my linux, but not on windows. Code is a more structured rewrite of a program that was existing and running before. Now I implemented all communication btw PyQt objects in the signal/slot system, but the crashes remain. Any idea where to start looking?

Comment: forgot to add: crash happens on the .show() call of the main window

Comment: @grgrsr. As I said before: it's impossible to say without seeing actual code. You will have to try to isolate the issue so that you can produce a small test case that reproduces the problem. Just remove chunks of code until the problem disappears; then start adding smaller chunks back until it reappears, etc, etc.

Comment: ok I found the bug, it is completely unrelated to all this: if a `QtGui.QAction` is created with an `QtGui.QtIcon` that was instantiated with `None` as an icon, then the segfault is thrown on `show()` if that action was added to a toolbar or menu... Nevertheless, I learned something unrelated, but important here. Thanks a lot!