# How do I keep GUI from freezing, while calling a function? (PyQT4, Python3)

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, pyqt4, qthread

### Question Background:

I'm new to PyQT4. I am developing a program with it and I am web scraping to get data into my program. While the information is downloading my GUI locks up. I would like to call this function in a separate background thread, perhaps using QThread, but I am having a tough time wrapping my head around QThread, Qt in general, and the slot/signal way of communication.

I have read about making a generic worker thread that will call any  function passed to it. I don't know how to implement it in my main file so that I can run my functions as a background process. If any example code could be shown, please explain each line in detail as I am not understanding the process.

### Questions:

1. How can I prevent my GUI from freezing while a function is running?
2. How could I use a background thread to run functions from my class?

### Code:

My ui is loaded in from an external file created by Qt 4 Designer.

[Full files on Github](https://github.com/mkelley88/BiddergyBrowser)

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
```

main.py (Main file)

```
def connections():
    # If button is clicked, call summary(), which web scrapes 
    # for data. This could take 5-30 seconds, this freezes UI.
    ui.btnRefreshSummary.clicked.connect(lambda: summary())

# Refresh items in gui
def refresh_ui():
    if summary_data != []:
        ui.valWatching.setText(summary_data[0])
        ui.valBidding.setText(summary_data[1])
        ui.valWon.setText(summary_data[2])
        ui.valNotWon.setText(summary_data[3])
        ui.valPurchases.setText(summary_data[4])
        ui.valInvoices.setText(summary_data[5])

def login():
    # Scrape website and login while in background; 
    # This locks up GUI until it completes.
    # Pretend this sleep command is the time it takes to login
    time.sleep(5)  # <-This would lock it up for 5 seconds

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    connections()
    # Load credentials from file.
    with open('login.txt') as f:
        credentials = f.readline().strip().split(':')
    f.closed

    # Login, download summary, then refresh the UI.
    b = Biddergy()
    b.login(credentials[0],credentials[1])
    summary_data = b.summary()
    b.logout()

    refresh_ui()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: SO doesn't work that way. It's you that must post the example code and explain what *specific* problems you are having in getting it to work the way you want.

Comment: @ekhumoro You don't have to be rude. Just simply telling me that using QThread would work, or offering other libraries to look into seem like a better response. It seems like every time I ask for help here on Stack, I usually always get this type of comment, or else someone closes my question. My problem is that I don't know what to use for my situation. I'm not expecting someone to write my code for me.

Comment: I'm sorry you feel that way, but I'm afraid I don't see anything wrong with my comment, which was simply intended as advice on how to improve your question (and increase your chances of getting answers). Your question is currently far too broad and open-ended.

Comment: I apologize if i took it the wrong way. I would gladly provide basic code, but I don't even have a basic understanding of how to do what I need to do. This was the point of the question.  All I know is that my GUI locks up, and I need a solution that will allow me to run a function without locking up the GUI. I understand there may be more then one solution to my problem, but I don't feel it was that broad. "How do I update a PyQT4 GUI while running a function?"

Comment: Write a very simple, self-contained web-scraper script that shows the main problem that you are trying to solve (i.e. locking up the UI). Then add in an attempted solution based on your current research efforts. This should result in a much more specific question, and give potential answerers a clearer idea of what you are trying to do (and where you are going wrong).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not clear from the example code why `connections()` *would* block (given the code it contains), or why `login()` *shouldn't* block (given that that is what login dialogs normally do). But anyway, the worker class in your example can be converted to a `QThread` like this:

```
class Worker(QThread):
    intReady = pyqtSignal(int)

    def run(self):
        for i in range(1, 10):
            time.sleep(1)
            self.intReady.emit(i)
```

and then it can be used like this:

```
    # connections()
    # login()
    def slot(arg='finished'): print(arg)
    thread = Worker()
    thread.intReady.connect(slot)
    thread.finished.connect(slot)
    thread.start()
```

There are many other ways of achieving the same thing - but which one is most appropriate, and how it would actually be implemented, depends on the details of how your application is intended to work.

Comment: This is not the full code, the login() and summary() functions take no arguments and (in the background) uses Robobrowser and BeautifulSoup to download, parse a web page, then login to the site and download more data into an array. While these are working on scraping the website, the GUI which shows the information from the site, remains frozen until the functions are complete. I would like to run any function I have or may have in this worker class using something like self.pushtothread( login() ) so I can execute a function without locking the  UI.

Comment: @MatthewKelley. If you try the code in my answer, you will see that the code executed inside `QThread.run()` does not block the GUI. So just call whatever function you like in there (so long as it doesn't attempt to update the GUI).

Comment: This has indeed pointed me in the right direction. Thank you. I have managed to get functions to run in the worker thread if I hard code them in the class under "def run(self): "  I wonder if there is a way to send the worker thread any function to work on. For instance, if i wanted to call a function "doStuff()" by passing it on from the main thread, without having to hard code it into the worker class.

Comment: @MatthewKelley. Wrap the function(s) in a `QObject` subclass and then [move it to the thread](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qobject.html#moveToThread). There should be lots of examples around showing how to do this: [here is one of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29636121/984421) that you might find useful. There is also a Qt Wiki article that is well worth reading: [Threads, Events, QObjects](http://wiki.qt.io/ThreadsEventsQObjects) (it doesn't matter if you don't know C++ - it is still a very useful overview).

Comment: I still haven't got it figured out yet. I have spent the last few days just trying to figure out QThread. I've looked over the examples you have provided, along with many more. While I've managed to get my code running in a thread, I have still not been able to send a function to a new thread. You have been very helpful, but I feel as if I'm just dragging this out on here. I'm not sure if that is allowed on this site and because of that I am afraid to keep asking questions on this page. I usually learn new things very quickly, I'm not sure why QThread has been so complicated for me.

Comment: @MatthewKelley. Don't worry about adding more comments. If necessary, you can just start a new question (so long as it doesn't duplicate the current one). I don't think there's any way to move a *function* to a thread. You have to make the function into the method of a `QObject` subclass, and then move an instance of that class to the thread. Is there some specific reason why you need to move the functions themselves? What exactly are these functions? Are they something you have written yourself?

Comment: I am writing a program to access a local auction site. I've moved my auction specific code/functions to an external class (Scrapers.py) to make it reusable for future programs. I am using 'b = AuctionClass' and I call 'b.login(user, pass)' to login. I then need data, so I call 'summary_data = b.summary()' where summary will return a list. I will have more functions like this, and I want to be able to tell them to run in a background thread in order to keep the user free to move around the UI without locking it up while new data is downloaded.

Comment: @MatthewKelley. I still don't see why you can't wrap this external scraper class in a `QObject` subclass. Or in other words: why can't you use the [Delegation Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern)?

Comment: I know you are not able to see my entire code, I have placed a copy on Github: [Here](https://github.com/mkelley88/BiddergyBrowser) where it will remain for the foreseeable future. Perhaps this will allow you to help me better. I am in just a bit over my head, I could use a more specific example of how to wrap a class in a QObject subclass. I don't think I know how to do that.

Comment: @MatthewKelley. It's very simple, and the link in my previous comment shows it very clearly. Look at the first Java example. The wrapper class keeps an internal instance of the delegate, and then just calls its methods when needed. That's all there is to it.

Comment: PS: In fact, I've just noticed your `Biddergy` class is itself a good example of delegation. It creates an instance of `RoboBrowser`, and then delegates to it in all its methods.

Answer (score 2):

With this updated code, I am finally able to start my functions in the background. Now off to learning how to make my background thread communicate with the main UI thread. Much thanks to @ekhumoro for being extremely patient with me.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
from PySide.QtCore import QThread, QObject, Signal, Slot
from main_gui import Ui_MainWindow  # my UI from Qt4 Designer(pyside-uic)
from Scrapers import Biddergy       # My own class
import sys
import queue

class BiddergyWrapper(QThread):
    def __init__(self, q, loop_time=1.0/60):
        self.q = q
        self.timeout = loop_time
        super(BiddergyWrapper, self).__init__()

    def onThread(self, function, *args, **kwargs):
        self.q.put((function, args, kwargs))

    def run(self):
        while True:
            try:
                function, args, kwargs = self.q.get(timeout=self.timeout)
                function(*args, **kwargs)
            except queue.Empty:
                self.idle()

    def idle(self):
        pass

    def _summary(self):
        b.summary()

    def summary(self):
        self.onThread(self._summary)

    def _login(self):
        b.login()

    def login(self):
        self.onThread(self._login())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    ui.btnRefreshSummary.clicked.connect(lambda: bw.summary())

    # Load credentials from file.
    with open('login.txt') as f:
        credentials = f.readline().strip().split(':')

    # Login, download summary, then refresh the UI.
    b = Biddergy(credentials[0], credentials[1])
    request_queue = queue.Queue()
    bw = BiddergyWrapper(request_queue)
    bw.start()

    # Run QApplication
    app.exec_()
    # Begin "Graceful stop?"
    bw.quit()
    b.logout()
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: Glad to see you have finally achieved what you wanted.